# How do I fade in an object which is rotating - Flash

Tags: adobe-flash

I have animated a lined circle to rotate but I want it to fade in while its rotating.

When I add a keyframe to create the fade, it thinks i'm meaning the rotation which speeds it up which I don't want.

Can anyone tell me how to add a simple fade in to an object which is all ready in motion?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind using ActionScript?

Comment: I don't really get into the action script part. Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: Without seeing the timeline it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are fading **must be an object**
Set 2 key frames for the begining and the end of the fading and change the alpha settings, the first key frame to 100% and the last to 0%